# Structuring main method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python script that will do 3 things:

1. check to see if a file exists in a directory
2. copy specific files from one directory to another, and
3. execute another python script.

Right now if I run the script it runs through all 3 functions, regardless of if the file exists in the test directory.

What I want it to do is check to see if the file exists. If it does, copy it, and once it's copied execute the other script. I am having trouble figuring out a simple way to link them all together. Here is my script:

```
import os
import os.path
from os import path
import shutil


def check_file():
    file_exists = False
    for deploy_file in os.listdir("C:\\test1\\test.txt"):
        if deploy_file.startswith("test"):
            file_exists = True
        else:
            exit(1)
    print file_exists


def copy_file():
    src = "C:\\test1\\"
    dst = "C:\\test2\\"

    files = [i for i in os.listdir(src) if i.startswith("test") and path.isfile(path.join(src, i))]
    print files
    for f in files:
        shutil.copy(path.join(src, f), dst)


def run_script():
    os.system("pathofscript") # for testing its just a script that prints "hello world"


def main():
    check_file()
    copy_file()
    run_script()


main()
```

So by running this as-is the output will be:

```
True
['test.txt']
"hello world"
```

How can I write my `main()` method to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: You need to use `return` statements to make these functions produce a programmatically useful result (`print` is not programmatically useful). Then you can *use* that result in the main method, e.g. controlling the other methods with `if check_file():`

Comment: Side-note: Your entire `check_file` function is a slow (possibly non-portable) equivalent to `os.path.isfile("C:\\test1\\test.txt")`.

Comment: The file names I am searching for will not be exactly the same every time, but they will always begin with the string "request". How would I factor that into this function if I wrote it as you suggested?

Comment: The simplest code to do that would be to use the `glob` module. `for path in glob.iglob(r'C:\some\path\request*'):` would filter and iterate the matches for you. Note the `r` prefix on the string; that makes it a raw string literal so you don't need to escape all the embedded backslashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify if the file exists with an if statement then run the other two functions. You will have to update `check_file()` to return True or False

```
def check_file():
    file_exists = False
    for deploy_file in os.listdir("C:\\test1\\test.txt"):
        if deploy_file.startswith("test"):
            file_exists = True
        else:
            file_exists = False
    return file_exists
```

Then you can use this as your main function

```
def main():
    if check_file():
        copy_file()
        run_script()
    else:
        exit(1)
```